# Noun declension in masculine monosyllabic nouns (non nominative cases)

Tags: noun, accusative, declension

Isn´t this rule correct?

The following highlighted in uppercase are my answers:

"Wir hängen sein Bild über ______
(der Tisch) den TischEN
(der Schrank) den SchrankEN"

Comment: What did a declension table tell you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_nouns#Declension_classes

Comment: The question is about whether a rule is correct, not the declension of the words given as examples. Please consider this before VTC.

Comment: Could you quote the concerned rule? The headline seems not to serve that purpose well.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, as you can tell by by looking at the declension tables for the examples in question. There are some masculine nouns whose accusative case is declined with an "-n", but that doesn't mean there's any kind of rule. Some examples are "Riese" and "Hase". But at best it's a trend which you can use as a memory aid in some cases. Noun declension is mainly a matter of memorization, learn the most common patterns and memorize the exceptions of which there are many. Many YouTube videos claim you can avoid the work with some relatively simple rules, but on YouTube its views that matter, not accuracy.